# Create faster loop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Got a loop that I think takes forever. It's working but takes 10 minutes to finish. Can any point me in a direction that makes this go faster? I know the Pivot takes time, but I hope any here have a idea. The loop goes through about 40-80 cells.

```
Sub GetStores()

Dim store As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Stores").Select
Range("A2").Select
Store= ActiveCell.Value


Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

Sheets("salescube").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell1").PivotFields( _
    "[DimGeography].[Location].[Country]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell1").PivotFields( _
    "[DimGeography].[Location].[Region]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell1").PivotFields( _
    "[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel].&[" & store & "]")

   Range("A:A,C:D").Select
Selection.Copy
 Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A2").Value
Range("B3").Select



Sheets("Stores").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Store = ActiveCell.Value

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT
[The Pivot, most cant be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phOe7.jpg)

Forgot to mention the hyperlink that refers back to the first sheet ("Stores")

Comment: 1) where is located your Pivot Table? 2) When you copy columns `A:A,C:D` It's your intention to copy only records from the Pivot Table? 3) Would it be ok to copy only values? As you have seen in the answers already provided there are several improvements to be done to your code, however there may be others that has not been mentioned due to the lack of info. Would you post a picture of your PivotTable and the data to be copy if not within the pivot table and one of the sheets after the copy just a reasonable size so we can see expected output.

Comment: 1) the pivot is in the same workbook. 2) i changed the selection    Range("A1:A118,C1:D118").Select

Comment: as you might can tell this is my first time posting ;)

Comment: 1) I referred to the address of the PT so I guess starts at `A1` 2) so you are copying data from the PT only 3) what about copying only values (not formatting)?

Comment: @EEM 1 and 2 are corect. ive added formating in column D (shows values <=0) that needs to be moved.

Comment: for my understanding ... shouldn't the last statement before `Loop` read `Store` instead of `butikk`?

Comment: Its just me forgetting to change that value before posting

Comment: what is copied in cell `A2` is same as the value of the scope variable?

Comment: nothing is copied from `A2` that only sets the active cell

Comment: well not really... if you look at this line `ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A2").Value` you are using whatever was copied into cell `A2` of the new sheet (when the range `A:A,C:D` was copied) to name the new sheet... that's is my question what it's there it's same as the value of `store`?

Comment: Aah I see now as I tried it once more. The `A2`is a "hidden" cell with a formula that looks after the name of the store. If that ain a store, its a fault witch sets of another cell. With the new macro you made these "help"cells now show, that's a thing I need to work out how to hide

Comment: so the cell hidden using formatting, do you want to retain the formula? once again question number 3 that you did not answer?

Comment: I might not been to clear in my answer but I mentioned that I had formatting in column D that needs to be moved. There are no formulas that needs to be moved over no. Again, thx for your patience's. This just opened a new door after a few years in the shadows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just wanted to show the code I ended up with that works perfectly. Again thanks @EEM

```
Sub GetStores_Published()
Dim Ptb As PivotTable
Dim Wsh As Worksheet
Dim rStore As Range, sStore As String
Dim rSrc As Range
Dim blErr As Boolean
Dim sShtName As String
Dim lPtbRowLst As Long

Rem Application Settings
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook

    Rem Set Objects
    Set rStore = .Sheets("Stores").Range("C3")
    sStore = rStore.Value2
    'Assuming there is only one PivotTable in Sheet salescube
    Set Ptb = .Sheets("Salescube").PivotTables(1)
    'Otherwise use line below
    'Set Ptb = .Sheets("salescube").PivotTables("Pivottabell1")

    Rem PivotTable Refresh and Set to Manual
    Ptb.RefreshTable

    Do
        With Ptb

            Rem Filter Pivot Table
            .PivotFields("[DimGeography].[Location].[Country]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            .PivotFields("[DimGeography].[Location].[Region]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
            blErr = False
            On Error Resume Next 'change [SalesChannel] med [Region]
            .PivotFields("[DimGeography].[Location].[Region]").VisibleItemsList = _
                Array("[DimGeography].[Location].[Region].&[" & sStore & "]")
            Rem Validates Filter on Store
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then blErr = True
            On Error GoTo 0
            If blErr Then GoTo NEXT_Store

            Rem Set PivotTable Last Row
            lPtbRowLst = -1 + .TableRange1.Row + .TableRange1.Rows.Count

            Rem Set New Sheet Name & Range to be Copied
            sShtName = .Parent.Range("B4").Value2
            Set rSrc = .Parent.Range("A1:A" & lPtbRowLst & ",C1:D" & lPtbRowLst)

        End With

        Rem Add Worksheet - Store
        On Error Resume Next
        .Sheets(sShtName).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set Wsh = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))


        Rem Copy Values from Source Range
        With Wsh
            .Name = sShtName

            Rem Use these lines to copy only values - does not use clipboard
            '.Range("A1:A" & lPtbRowLst).Value = rSrc.Areas(1).Value2
            '.Range("B1:C" & lPtbRowLst).Value = rSrc.Areas(2).Value2

            Rem use these lines to copy\paste values & formats as in the original sheet - uses of clipboard. Added one more that gets all formats
            rSrc.Copy
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial
            Columns().AutoFit
            '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False     'Clears the clipboard

            .Cells(3, 2).Activate
        End With

        Rem Copy Values from Source Range
        With Wsh
            .Name = sShtName
            .Range("A1:A" & lPtbRowLst).Value = rSrc.Areas(1).Value2
            .Range("B1:C" & lPtbRowLst).Value = rSrc.Areas(2).Value2
            .Cells(3, 2).Activate
        End With

NEXT_Store:
        Rem Reset Store Range
        'Highlights Cell If PT Filter By Scope Failed
        If blErr Then rStore.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Set rStore = rStore.Offset(1, 0)
        sStore = rStore.Value2

    Loop Until sStore = Empty

End With

Rem Application Settings
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Before altering the pivot table, stop the calculations with:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell1").ManualUpdate = True
```

After the changes, resume the calculations with:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell1").ManualUpdate = False
```

Comment: exactly where in the macro should this be posted. Same as the other, this is New to me, the way i can use this

Answer (score 2):

generic hints: work with objects and avoid `.Select`

example: instead of

```
Sheets("Stores").Select
Range("A2").Select
Store= ActiveCell.Value
```

use

```
Store = Sheets("Stores").[A2]
```

(or `Sheets("Stores").Range("A2")` if you don't like the square brackets notation ... and yes we know that this is hardcoding and you may want to make some extra thoughts on how to avoid that as well ...)

instead of

```
Sheets("salescube").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell1").PivotFields( _
    "[DimGeography].[Location].[Country]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
```

use

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
    ' ...
    Set PT = Sheets("salescube").PivotTables("Pivottabell1")
    ' ... Do While
        PT.PivotFields("...").VisibleItemsList = "..."
    ' ... Loop
```

same for the Copy/paste ... and you may eliminate the `ScreenUpdating` alltogether.

---

**Details:**

```
Sub GetStores()
Dim StoreIndex As Integer
Dim StoreRange As Range
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet

    ' prepare range and index for stores
    Set StoreRange = Sheets("Stores").[A2]
    StoreIndex = 1

    ' starting from here you can access all stores using StoreRange(StoreIndex, 1)

    ' prepare Pivot Table object
    Set PT = Sheets("SalesCube").PivotTables("PivotTabell1")


    Do While StoreRange(StoreIndex, 1) <> ""
        ' can't run this without having precise design of PT
        ' however at the end we have pivot filtered by current store

        ' PT.PivotFields( _
            "[DimGeography].[Location].[Country]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
        ' PT.PivotFields( _
            "[DimGeography].[Location].[Region]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
        ' PT .PivotFields( _
            "[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
            "[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel].&[" & StoreRange(StoreIndex, 1) & "]")

        ' create new sheet object and give it the name of current store
        Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        NewSheet.Name = StoreRange(StoreIndex, 1)

        ' copy to new sheet PT in current filter mode by intersecting PT with "A:A,C:D"
        ' note: Application.Intersect(range1, range2) returns a range
        Application.Intersect(PT.RowRange.CurrentRegion, PT.Parent.Range("A:A,C:D")).Copy NewSheet.[A1]

        ' increment loop counter
        StoreIndex = StoreIndex + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: suggest to use `Set PT = Sheets("salescube").PivotTables("Pivottabell1")` instead of `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabell1")` "avoid select"

Comment: of course ... I was about to update this - done ... thanks for that

Comment: can i bother you With a bigger example. This is a bit New to me, the way you explain it ;)

Comment: sure & with pleasure ... allow +/- 1 hour

Comment: theres a flaw (or something im missing) but it wont Select active cell after first round

Answer (score 0):

`butikk = ActiveCell.Value` needs to be `store = ActiveCell.Value`; otherwise you recalculate the same values again and again.
`"[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel].&[" & store & "]")` - I think there should be no "&" after the last dot.
What really takes time is that you copy whole columns `A:A` and `C:D`. You should find the last used row and copy from row 1 to that last row only. You can use this to get the last row number:

```
Public Function lastrow(Optional aSheet As Worksheet) As Long
    If aSheet Is Nothing Then Set aSheet = ActiveSheet
    lastrow = aSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Function
```

and then use `range(cells(1,1),cells(lastrow(),1)` and `range(cells(1,3),cells(lastrow(),4)` instead.
As you are working on several sheets qualify ranges and `cells` with the appropriate sheet name to avoid mistakes.

Comment: forgot to change butikk when posting.

Comment: the "." needs to be there, else a error is generated, but the function was a. The Copy-part was a great ad tho i only used     'Range("A1:A118").Select'

Answer (score 0):

This procedure includes some validations missing in your original code:

- Highlights the store value in worksheet `Stores` if fails the pivot table filter
- Deletes the worksheet to copy the selected data if already exist
- Avoids the use of the clipboard - optional (it also includes the option to use the clipboard as we need to copy the format of the original cells)
- Improves performance by disabling some application properties
- refresh the pivot table before proceeding with the filters
- use the pivottable properties to determine the range to be copied

Suggest to read these pages for deeper understanding of the resources used in the procedure

[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), [Application Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx), [Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html)

[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx), [GoSub...Return Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251648.aspx), [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)

[PivotTable Members (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835831.aspx), [Range.PasteSpecial Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx)

Let me know of any questions you might have about the procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetStores_Published()
Dim Ptb As PivotTable
Dim Wsh As Worksheet
Dim rStore As Range, sStore As String
Dim rSrc As Range
Dim blErr As Boolean
Dim sShtName As String
Dim lPtbRowLst As Long

    Rem Application Settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook

        Rem Set Objects
        Set rStore = .Sheets("Stores").Range("A2")
        sStore = rStore.Value2
        'Assuming there is only one PivotTable in Sheet salescube
        Set Ptb = .Sheets("salescube").PivotTables(1)
        'Otherwise use line below
        'Set Ptb = .Sheets("salescube").PivotTables("Pivottabell1")

        Rem PivotTable Refresh and Set to Manual
        Ptb.RefreshTable

        Do
            With Ptb

                Rem Filter Pivot Table
                .PivotFields("[DimGeography].[Location].[Country]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
                .PivotFields("[DimGeography].[Location].[Region]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
                blErr = False
                On Error Resume Next
                .PivotFields("[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel]").VisibleItemsList = _
                    Array("[DimGeography].[Location].[SalesChannel].&[" & sStore & "]")
                Rem Validates Filter on Store
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then blErr = True
                On Error GoTo 0
                If blErr Then GoTo NEXT_Store

                Rem Set PivotTable Last Row
                lPtbRowLst = -1 + .TableRange1.Row + .TableRange1.Rows.Count

                Rem Set New Sheet Name & Range to be Copied
                sShtName = .Parent.Range("A2").Value2
                Set rSrc = .Parent.Range("A1:A" & lPtbRowLst & ",C1:D" & lPtbRowLst)

            End With

            Rem Add Worksheet - Store
            On Error Resume Next
            .Sheets(sShtName).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set Wsh = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))


            Rem Copy Values from Source Range
            With Wsh
                .Name = sShtName

                Rem Use these lines to copy only values - does not use clipboard
                '.Range("A1:A" & lPtbRowLst).Value = rSrc.Areas(1).Value2
                '.Range("B1:C" & lPtbRowLst).Value = rSrc.Areas(2).Value2

                Rem use these lines to copy\paste values & formats as in the original sheet - uses of clipboard
                rSrc.Copy
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False     'Clears the clipboard

                .Cells(3, 2).Activate
            End With

            Rem Copy Values from Source Range
            With Wsh
                .Name = sShtName
                .Range("A1:A" & lPtbRowLst).Value = rSrc.Areas(1).Value2
                .Range("B1:C" & lPtbRowLst).Value = rSrc.Areas(2).Value2
                .Cells(3, 2).Activate
            End With

NEXT_Store:
            Rem Reset Store Range
            'Highlights Cell If PT Filter By Scope Failed
            If blErr Then rStore.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            Set rStore = rStore.Offset(1, 0)
            sStore = rStore.Value2

        Loop Until sStore = Empty

    End With

    Rem Application Settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Impressive @EEM. Thats a brand new way for me to write codes. Gonna learn alot from this post.

Comment: That's the idea to encourage you to continue working and developing your programming skills...

Comment: Two things i Wonder: 1) i need to get the columns to     `Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit` I can see where i should put it, but i dont wanna mess up your work. 2) the column C that's copied is % and that's lost during `copy/paste`-parte

Comment: Ive already tried it on a few sheets where I got columns with regions and stores that needs to be put in sheets, so I just changed `[SalesChannel]`to `[region]`. Not sure if its much faster, but its wait cooler ;)

Comment: 1) will add that to the code 2)That was the reason of my question number 3) about copying values only (no formatting)... It will be help a lot to see a picture of the pivot table.

Comment: Can't tell you about the changed [SalesChannel]to [region] as I don't have a visual on the pivot table but try and measure the timing.

Comment: so please answer pending question because that will imply some changes to the code.

Comment: Ok i'll do some small changes to the code and let know you know hen ready so you can try again.. about the [SalesChannel] to [region] what columns are they?

Comment: the regeion/saleschannel are listed in the same sheets `stores` where stores are in column A and region in C. But I just use the same macro you created and do the changes and `Call` when regions needs to get up there

Comment: @amazing. ive been reading your links the last few hours. going to lots by the looks of things. thx for your help an patience with my first post.

Comment: Changes done, now keeps the original format of the `A2` and the % in columns `C`

Comment: No problem... as I said the idea is that you feel part of the community and are encourage to work on your skills, we are always here to help you on that. Glad to be of service. If you are satisfy with the answer then acknowledge it and help us to keep the site updated...

Comment: With my first day here im sure that I will be in here regularly and I will help with what I can, not sure how yet, but I guess that it will come with time.

Comment: I sorry to bother you with one more question. I get the formats but I loose the hyperlink that's in `C3` (see picture in my initial post) and the columns doesn't `autofit`